# Find between which values the 20% central will be at.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, confidence-interval, standard-error

> The measurements of the times of a group of children competing in a race of
> The 100-m dash follows a normal distribution with a mean of 13.4 s and a standard deviation of 1.2 s. Among which values will be found the central 20% of runners?

Since we are given the 20% central, means the 20% of values around the mean, which also means the level of confidence is $p=0.2=1-\alpha\Rightarrow \alpha=0.8$, so $Z_{\alpha/2}=Z_{0.4}=0.255$ by looking at the table, hence the values will be the extreme values of the interval $[\mu-error, \mu+error]$, and $error=Z_{\alpha/2}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ but we don't have the $\sqrt{n}$, do we? Hence how else should I do this?

Comment: What is $n$ in this context? The normal distribution is a continuous one, not discrete. There no count of outcomes, as there are infinitely many. I'm pretty sure you've mixed up your formulas.